# Jena GenericRuleReasoner

Tags: jena, inference, reasoning, jena-rules

What happens if we put a variable in the head of a GenericRuleReasoner, which does not appear in the body of the rule?

For instance if we have the following rule :

```
rule1: (?x rdf:type :Person) -> (?y :father ?x)
```

The rule says that every person has a father.
Suppose we have a triple `:a rdf:type :Person` 
How does the reasoner behaves here? Will it create a new triple with blank node like `_x :father :a` ?

Comment: "The rule says that every person has a father. "  Why do you say that? Whether it says that depends on what Jena does with that rule.  If you want "a new triple with blank node like _x :father :a", then you just need to write `(?x rdf:type :Person), makeTemp(?y) -> (?y :father ?x)`.  It's all described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will complain about that. It is, after all, ambiguous: do you mean 'there is a `?y` such that...' or 'for any `?y` ....'?

From what you say it's clear that you expect former, the existential version, because that's what introducing a bNode does. So try:

```
rule1: makeTemp(?y), (?x rdf:type ex:Person)  -> (?y ex:fatherOf ?x)
```

or

```
rule1: makeInstance(?y, ex:father, ?x), (?x rdf:type ex:Person) -> (?y ex:fatherOf ?x)
```

the latter of which will give you a consistent father node, whereas the former simply introduces a bNode.

Comment: I mean there exists ?y so that ?y :father ?x

Comment: Yes, I realised that from what you said about introducing a bNode, which means exactly that. I'll modify my answer to make it clear.